# Does it make sense to compare distributions of p-values?

Tags: distributions, p-value

I have 2 lists of variables. Let's say both lists contain approximately 500 variables.

Each of the variable in these lists allows me to split a cohort into 2. 
So, for each of the variable, I have computed a Mann-Whitney test.

I thus have 2 distributions of p-values, one for each list.

Does it make sense to compare these  distributions of p-values?
If so, should I just use the same statistical tests that one uses when comparing 2 natural distributions?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on exactly how these variables "allow me to split a cohort into two"? It's not really clear what you mean by "variable" or by "list," except that at least one of these words appears to be used in an unconventional way.

Comment: I have often heard people say that under the null hypothesis the p-value is uniformly distributed.  The definition of the p-value is the probability of obtaining a value as extreme or more extreme than the observed when the null hypothesis is observed.  The definition seems to imply a unique value rather than a distribution.

Comment: I like the question the OP raises but I realize it opens up a can of worms that could lead to a lot of discussion that may be confusing and  could move in many directions because the issue is so broad. Maybe some specificity could narrow the discussion but I am not sure how the OP could edit the question to achieve that.

Comment: Do you have two 'lists' of 500 p-values?

Comment: Yes, that is the case (2 lists of 500 p-values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular reason to avoid the usual analytic techniques here. In a related area of combining $p$-values there are a number of methods which transform the $p$-values first so you might prefer to follow their example. One obvious option would be to transform them into normal deviates and then analyse them.

Comment: I never interpreted distribution of p-values to mean a distribution associated with a collection of calculated p-values.  In my comments I was thinking of theoretical construct of what a p-value would do in repeated testing when a particular hypothesis is assumed too be correct as in providing a uniform distribution for the p-value when the null hypothesis is assumed to be correct.  If I read your answer right you are thinking of a collection of p-values coming from actually applying multiple tests.  In that case I would agree the standard methods of p-value adjustment would be appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelChernick that is indeed my assumption. It seems from the number of close votes that I may be in a minority here but I felt there was something sensible behind the question.